# ARKit and AVCamera simultaneously

Tags: arkit

As there is no autofocus in ARKit, I wanted to load ARKit in a view that is half the screen and second half will have AVFoundation -> AVCamera.
Is it possible to load AVCamera and ARKit simultaneously in same app?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

#### Nope.

ARKit uses AVCapture internally (as explained in the [WWDC talk introducing ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602/)). Only one `AVCaptureSession` can be running at a time, so if you run your own capture session it’ll suspend ARKit’s session (and break tracking).

**Update:** However, in iOS 11.3 (aka "ARKit 1.5"), ARKit enables autofocus by default, and you can choose to disable it with the [`isAutoFocusEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2942262-isautofocusenabled) option.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the camera focus would disrupt the tracking - so this is definitely not possible (right now at least).

Update: See @rickster answer above.

Comment: Autofocus is both possible and on by default in iOS 11.3 (see [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47725672/957768)), but not on earlier iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use AVFoundation with ARKit by calling                     self.sceneView.session.run(self.sceneView.session.configuration!) right after taking the photo.

Use self.captureSession?.stopRunning() right after taking photo to make the session resume faster.

```
self.takePhoto()
self.sceneView.session.run(self.sceneView.session.configuration!)

 func startCamera() {
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
       let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
        if (captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {
            captureSession.addInput(input)
            if (captureSession.canAddOutput(cameraOutput)) {
                captureSession.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        } else {
            print("issue here : captureSesssion.canAddInput")
        }
    } else {
        print("some problem here")
    }
}

func takePhoto() {
    startCamera()
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    self.captureSession?.stopRunning()
}
```